# What functions model this relationship?

Tags: linear-algebra, periodic-functions

I'm currently working a bit on an AI, and in order for it to function, it must be able to quickly predict where a point will be in space, given any distance. The movement of this point may be modeled as a linear graph 1 up until it reaches a maximum y value, at which point the movement begins to decrease with the slope -1 until the minimum y value.

The equation for the upward cycle of the function is $y=min+x-?$, but when the function is on a downward cycle, it becomes $y=max-x+?$. The $?$ in the equation represents a value which basically cancels out all growth in $x$ beyond the $min$ and $max$ respectively. For some reason, I strongly suspect that differential calculus is the means by which this can be solved, but I am currently only on a pre-calculus level of mathematics.

What I need is a function that is periodic and bounces between the min and max like a sine wave (or a periodic absolute value graph), but which has no curve. Does there exist any such function? If not, how may I go about finding an equation for this relationship?

Comment: Are you saying that the motion of the point is nonlinear?  Is there any reason not to use alternating lines based on the most recent "reflection" event?

Comment: After reading again... Have you considered using $x\sin x\over |\sin x|$ and defining the value as $0$ for $x=0+2k\pi$?

Comment: The motion is entirely linear. The slope remains linear. Like an absolute value graph, but I want two y values at which the graph reflects. The problem is, I think like a programmer; I could describe at length _how_ to solve the problem (and have a subpar solution easily). I'd like to see how to solve the problem mathematically. [This is similar] to what the graph should look like(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Aliasing-folding.svg/300px-Aliasing-folding.svg.png)

Comment: For posterity, I recently stumbled upon an excellent approximation: asin(sin(x)). For reasons not fully in my realm of understanding, the computer approximation yields a periodic triangle wave

Comment: Also, that equation has an amplitude of pi/2, so with the appropriate transformations, the function approximates pixel-by-pixel bouncing in a bounded region of any width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either want http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave. I don't think that they are expressible as "equations" in the way you're thinking, though they are certainly well defined functions. I would also guess that most programming languages would allow you to make such a function quite easily.

Comment: Ah! Triangle waves! That's exactly what I wanted, but I really couldn't think of any way to approximate them mathematically in a formula. I did manage sawtooth waves by whipping together a modulus operation. Too be fair, I did imagine additive sine waves, but didn't want to fool around too much with them >.<

Comment: You should be able to do something similar with triangle waves